# Being blocked by CORS: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, express, axios, cors, preflight

I am getting the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/api/investments' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Whenever I try to post some data to my api using the following axios command

```
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
      : null
  );
const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${login.token}`,
      },
    };
 await axios
      .post(`${Config.SERVER_ADDRESS}/api/investments`, investmentObj, config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(investmentObj);
        notify(`${response.data.name} investimento cadastrado com Sucesso`);
        history.push(`/app/investment/${response.data._id}`);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);

        notify(err.response.data, 'danger');
      });
```

I don't know what to do, since I am using the following middleware:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers'
  );

  app.use(cors());
  next();
});
```

I think that my issue is related to the Authorization in the headers, since my other api calls are working... Hopefully any of you guys will help me with such preflight request

Comment: Does adding `Authorization` to the list of `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` help?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I just added the following code `app.options('*', cors());` and now it is everything working...
Check that out on the documentation from CORS npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers'
  );

  app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
  next();
});
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: `{ credentials: true, origin: true }` is very insecure!